# How to share the Outlook add-in VSTO file over network with normal users without Admin rights

Tags: vsto, file-sharing

We have developed a Outlook Add-in and want to share the add-in over network and deploy on user machine who does not have Admin rights. what is the best way to share the VSTO files over network since sending as email attachment is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a per-user add-in and then create a ClickOnce installer and publish it on a network share instead. See [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information